# Play Framework 2.2.1 / How should controller handle a queryString in JSON format

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

My client side executes a server call encompassing data (queryString) in a JSON object like this:

```
?q={"title":"Hello"}   //non encoded for the sample but using JSON.stringify actually
```

What is an efficient way to retrieve the `title` and `Hello` String?

I tried this:

```
val params = request.queryString.map {case(k,v) => k->v.headOption}
```

that returns the `Tuple`: `(q,Some({"title":"hello"}))`

I could further extract to retrieve the values (although I would need to manually map the JSON object to a Scala object), but I wonder whether there is an easier and shorter way.

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just POST the JSON in the request body?

Comment: @Ryan Because the actual call concerns the "index" Rest method that uses GET by convention. Parameters would allow to filter on the returned results.

Comment: @Ryan actually it's correct to `GET`, if you intend to receive a resource from a RESTful service. `POST` should not be used for such requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you intend to pluck only the `q` parameter from a request and don't intend to do so via a `route` you could simply grab it directly:

```
val q: Option[String] = request.getQueryString("q")
```

Next you'd have to parse it as a JSON Object:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val jsonObject: Option[JsValue] = q.map(raw: String => json.parse(raw))
```

with that you should be able to check for the components the `jsonObject` contains:

```
val title: Option[String] = jsonObject.flatMap { json: JsValue =>
  (json \ "title").asOpt[String]
}
```

In short, omitting the types you could use a for comprehension for the whole thing like so:

```
val title = for {
  q <- request.getQueryString("q")
  json <- Try(Json.parse(q)).toOption
  titleValue <- (json \ "title").asOpt[String]
} yield titleValue
```

`Try` is defined in `scala.util` and basically catches Exceptions and wraps it in a processable form.

I must admit that the last version simply ignores Exceptions during the parsing of the raw JSON String and treats them equally to "no title query has been set".
That's not the best way to know what actually went wrong.

In our productive code we're using implicit shortcuts that wraps a `None` and `JsError` as a `Failure`:

```
val title: Try[String] = for {
  q <- request.getQueryString("q") orFailWithMessage "Query not defined"
  json <- Try(Json.parse(q))
  titleValue <- (json \ "title").validate[String].asTry
} yield titleValue
```

Staying in the `Try` monad we gain information about *where it went wrong* and can provide that to the User.

`orFailWithMessage` is basically an implicit wrapper for an `Option` that will transform it into `Succcess` or `Failure` with the specified message.

`JsResult.asTry` is also simply a [pimped](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw) JsResult that will be `Success` or `Failure` as well.

Comment: I'm currently writing a similar solution, but I really like yours :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: I used to make usage of Scalaz with `Validation` mechanism instead of the Scala's `Try` but it well works too :) `Validation` also having a wrapper on the `Option`.

Comment: Yepp, they are quite similar. Before 2.10 we used Scalaz for exactly that purpose, but decided to drop it in favor of the `Try` instead.

Comment: I should grab a new comparison about variants of exception handling in Scala :)